# syntax error on jquery-1.11.0.min.js : line 4 character 16126 on Internet Explorar 8 or earliar

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-error

When I test my application on IE 7 I got an error on

```
    jquery-1.11.0.min.js, line 4 character 16126

    it says that: SCRIPT1002: Syntax error 
    for the line: return a.JSON.parse(b+"");
```

I googled for the solution and some people tells to add the following script to my application

```
    https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js
```

So I added this to my application like below:

```
    <script src="/Scripts/json2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

But still I got this problem and my application and it is not working . Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: Why you would support so old browser versions?

Comment: If the error is mentioned in jQuery, it actually means that it comes from your code somewhere, not jQuery. And I think like Jens, we have to drop support for dinosaur browsers like IE7. The problem probably comes from the dinosaur itself.

Comment: Still working for old browsers? The best thing you can do is to **upgrade**. You can try with an older version of jQuery (if it is jQuery who returns the error).

Comment: Its all about client's requirement my friends ...  :(